# meaning of java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: null

Tags: java, memory, operating-system, jvm

What does java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: **null** imply.

I.E why is the reason stated as null.
I saw this exception when I was trying to work with sun.misc.unsafe.
Now I know we shouldn't be using this library. But aside from that What I would like to know is how to understand when this exception is thrown. what are the reasons for which it could be thrown?
In my case, I believe it was probably triggered to allocate a large memory size.

What other scenarios would this come from??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: @Vipin This [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html] would help you out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

Comment: @Abhinav..The link gives a 404. Also, I'm looking for a specific type "NULL"

Comment: The null value is not a "type" it's the detailed error message and those are not defined by the language specification. An OOME was created with a null message and processed by defective code.

Comment: This is where you need to check the stack trace to see the likely cause. If there is no stack trace, you need to check if thus has happened many times and find the first time.

Comment: And if you want someone to track this down without a stacktrace, you need to tell us a lot more.  Like what version of Java you were using, what vendor, what method was called to trigger the exception, etcetera.

Comment: FWIW, one scenario is calling `throw new OutOfMemoryError(null)` in user code.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` was thrown without an error message. Other answerers are correct that there can be different reasons, and you will need to check the stack trace. In my recent case, it was due to attempting to allocate a String Buffer larger than the java limit in JDK 11, where this error was thrown without a message: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8230744 (fixed in jdk 15).